# How to gerenare allure report on RobotFramework

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, robotframework, allure

I'm trying to gererate a report using allure but got an error that I can't fix. Can you help?

These are my libs

```
packaging==22.0
pluggy==1.0.0
pytest==7.2.0
requests==2.25.1
robotframework==6.0.1
robotframework-requests==0.9.4
six==1.16.0
tomli==2.0.1
urllib3==1.26.13
wincertstore==0.2
```

After installing allure I execute this command to run my test:

```
robot --listener allure_robotframework ./tests
```

I have googled and found out that to generate the report I should execute:

```
allure serve ./<path to folder containing results>
```

But instead of the report I get an error saying **allure is not recognized as an internal or external command**

I tried to install allure-command line but loos like pip is not able to find it

**By the way, my pip version is 22.3.1**

Comment: Pip is in no way related to the allure tools. Have you checked that the allure tool is in your ``PATH`` env? If you have not set that, you'll need to call it with the absolute path to the executable.

Comment: hello @Morkkis, tx for the anwer. I'm not sure how to install allure tools. Besides the libs I mentioned before, I checked the side packages folder and got the following:

-allure_commons
-allure_pytest
-allure_pytest-2.12.0.dist-info
-allure_python_commons-2.12.0.dist-info
-allure_robotframework
-allure_robotframework-2.12.0.dist-info
-AllureLibrary

Ant then, I added it to PATH. Still dont work

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood that you wish to use allure as stand-alone. If you are running your tests with the listener, you should already have the reports in your output directory. It will probably help locating them if you give the output path when specifying the listener with ``--listener allure_robotframework;/set/your/path/here``.

To use the tool separately, you'll need to install it normally from apt.

Comment: Yes, I do have the files generated on a specific direcotory but when I try to execute the command `allure serve` I get the error mentioned.  <br>
By the way, I'm using windows, can you tell how to install it ?

Comment: Tx for the help bro. I was able to fix it. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it runing the command `npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

At first of all you need install allure standalone to Windows via scoop or another way, details see [here](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_windows).

After this try run

```
allure --version
```

to see if installation is ok.

Only after this you need install `allure-robotframework` listener to your python environment, details [here](https://pypi.org/project/allure-robotframework/):

```
pip install allure-robotframework
```

Good Luck.